# How to find which FitNesse version is used

Tags: java, fitnesse

We are currently using a version of FiNesse at our work but do not know its version so wanted to know how to find which version of FitNesse is being used?

Thanks,
GS

Comment: Pls Go through [How to Ask on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking first query

Answer (score 5):

Add `${FITNESSE_VERSION}` to a page.